# Ant build and empty directories

Tags: ant, scp

For some reason, when I use `scp` to move files from my current machine to the server using `ant` it always ignores empty directories.

```
<scp todir="ec2-user@xx.x.x.xxx:/var/www/html" keyfile="${basedir}\..\keys\prod_default.pem" trust="true">
<fileset dir="${staging.dir}" />
</scp>
```

Why is the case?

Full Update verbose log:

```
D:\BUILD\SCRIPTS>ant -v -f getcom.xml update
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
Buildfile: D:\BUILD\SCRIPTS\getcom.xml
Detected Java version: 1.7 in: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre
Detected OS: Windows Server 2008 R2
parsing buildfile D:\BUILD\SCRIPTS\getcom.xml with URI = file:/D:/BUILD/SCRIPTS/getcom.xml
Project base dir set to: D:\BUILD\SCRIPTS
parsing buildfile jar:file:/C:/ant/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml
with URI = jar:file:/C:/ant/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
 [property] Loading D:\BUILD\SCRIPTS\build.properties
Build sequence for target(s) `update' is [update]
Complete build sequence is [update, upload, cleanup, staging, export, init, ]

update:
     [exec] Current OS is Windows Server 2008 R2
     [exec] Executing 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\subversion\\bin\\\svn' with arguments:
     [exec] 'update'
     [exec] 'D:\BUILD\SCRIPTS\..\_STAGING\GETOM'
     [exec] '--username'
     [exec] 'uuuu'
     [exec] '--password'
     [exec] 'uuuu'
     [exec]
     [exec] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
     [exec] not part of the command.
     [exec] Updating 'D:\BUILD\_STAGING\GETOM':
     [exec] At revision 134.
      [scp] Connecting to xx.0.0.100:22
      [scp] done.
      [scp] Connecting to xx.0.2.100:22
      [scp] done.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 8 seconds
```

Properties:

```
svn.repoBaseURL="https://uuu@uuuu.uuuu.com"
svn.username="uuuu"
svn.password="uuuu"
svn.bin=C://Program Files (x86)//subversion//bin//
MSBuildPath=C://WINDOWS//Microsoft.NET//Framework//v4.0.30319//MSBuild.exe
lib.path.ant-contrib=C:/ant/lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar
```

Please note, folder names have been changed.

Comment: Have you run it in verbose mode?

Comment: @AmitBhargava I have updated my question to show what I get in verbose mode.

Comment: Well, it seems to be taking lib.path.ant-contrib literally rather than substituting the values. Could you share your build properties file as well?

Comment: @AmitBhargava I have fixed that issue and have updated my question with the logs as it hasn't solved the original problem.

Comment: Is the list of empty directories always known? Can you create them in a separate step?

Comment: @AmitBhargava I shouldn't need to create a work around for this. I'm wondering is there a flag that I need to set to allow ant to include empty folders in scp tasks. Does scp include empty directories by default?

Comment: Well, if it's not happening one way, atleast you have a backup

Comment: I see `getcom.xml`, but `[...]\GETOM` (Note the absense of the letter 'C' in the latter)  Could this be the problem (i.e. you are trying to copy a non-existing directory as opposed to an empty one)?

Comment: @Attila It's not that I am having issues with copying any files/folders. They all get copied over from the correct place to the right remote location. However, all the empty directories are ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to come up with a workaround.  The way that Ant implements the scp means that empty directories are always skipped.

The gist of it is that the Scp class does this:

```
DirectoryScanner scanner = set.getDirectoryScanner(getProject());
Directory root = new Directory(scanner.getBasedir());
String[] files = scanner.getIncludedFiles();
if (files.length != 0) {
    ...
}
```

In other words, it only processes the directory if it contains at least one file.

There is a [patch for the Scp task code](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Misc/Q_22025533.html) you might consider, but that means a bespoke Ant build.

The two other approaches that come to mind are

- make the directories non-empty by populating with placeholder files (which you can delete once deployed)
- create the empty directories in a separate step

Comment: Thank you Martin. I thought this was the case. I'll take you first option of making sure all directories files at least have one file in them.